# How to replace partial groups in python regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a regex

```
(obligor_id): (\d+);(obligor_id): (\d+):
```

A sample match like below:

```
Match 1
Full match  57-95   `obligor_id: 505732;obligor_id: 505732:`
Group 1.    57-67   `obligor_id`
Group 2.    69-75   `505732`
Group 3.    76-86   `obligor_id`
Group 4.    88-94   `505732`
```

I am trying to partially replace the full match to the following:

`obligor_id: 505732;obligor_id: 505732:` -> `obligor_id: 505732;`

Two ways to achieve so,

1. replace group 3 and 4 with empty string
2. replace group 1 and 2 with empty string, and then replace group 4 to `(\d+);`

How can I achieve these 2 in python? I know there is a re.sub function, but I only know how to replace the whole, not partially replace group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `(obligor_id)` needs to be a group? Do you only replace repeating ids? If so, consider replacing the entire line that matches `obligor_id: (\d+);obligor_id: \1` with `"obligor_id: " + match.group(1)`.

Comment: Use `re.sub` with your pattern and `r'\1: \2;'` replacement. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxJo9S/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change capturing groups and reference them in the substitution string:

```
s = 'obligor_id: 505732;obligor_id: 505732:' 
re.sub(r'(obligor_id: \d+;)(obligor_id: \d+:)', r'\1', s)
# => 'obligor_id: 505732;
```

Comment: For using number variables in replacement strings, named reference syntax can be used: `re.sub(pat, r'\g<1>' + f'{my_number}', str)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers and advices:

I achieved them as below for future users:

```
re.sub(regex, r'\1: \2;', str)
re.sub(regex, r'\3: \4;', str)
```